# Discord.py Get all members with role given in message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This seems trivial, but I have a strange problem.

I check this condition in on_message (just a snippet, I have more conditions there and they work perfectly):

```py
elif message.content.startswith("?ranklist "):
    await rankLister(cls, message)
```

This is the function I use to list all members of the role user supplies in message.

```py
async def rankLister(cls, message):
    rankToAnalizeStr = message.content[10:]
    logging.info("Asked for %s role members", rankToAnalizeStr)

    for role in message.guild.roles: 
        if role.name == rankToAnalizeStr:
            rankToAnalize = role
            break
        rankToAnalize = ""

    if rankToAnalize:
        memberNames = "\n".join(i.name for i in rankToAnalize.members)

        embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="", color=0xff0000)
        embed.set_author(name="", url="https://tieronetact.com")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/734014025834430525.png")
        embed.add_field(name="Lista osób z rangą {}".format(rankToAnalizeStr), value=memberNames, inline=True)

        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

The format of the message is following:

> ?ranklist roleNameHere

Hence the string cutting at the beginning. Now what happens is I get only the members connected to voice WHEN THE BOT IS BOOTING (not when the function is called), which is really strange, because I don't reference the voice channels in any way. I'd like to get all the members (including those not connected to voice, both online and offline).

Pic ref:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHVYr.png

Comment: Might be connected to https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents

Comment: @TinNguyen Thank you! That solved the problem. They had to change something about the Gateway Intents though, because another thing I've had implemented stopped working today and started working again after enabling Server Members Intent. This other thing was monitoring when someone get's assigned a specific role, while he has another specific role already assigned (sort of guest -> registered user handling to generate automated message from the bot to the registered user).